# How do i write this C++ code in C. Linked List Iteration?

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

```cpp
// Recur for all the vertices adjacent to current vertex
list<int>::iterator i;
for (i = adj[src].begin(); i != adj[src].end(); ++i)
    if (!visited[*i])
        // Do Something
```

How do I write this code in C? I tried the following, is it correct?

```c
while (graph->adjLists[src]->next != NULL)
{
    int i = graph->adjLists[src]->vertex;
    if (!visited[i])
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    graph->adjLists[src] = graph->adjLists[src]->next;
```

Comment: No, because you're modifying the list. Of course this question is not answerable without knowing the types of `graph`, `adjLists` and so on.

Comment: It might help if you wrote out what the C++ code does. Get it to the point where you essentially have a homework assignment for which the C++ code is an answer. Then solve the homework assignment in C.

Answer (score 1):

Just comparing the two you can see they're not the same. Look at the role of the `i` variable for instance. *Probably* something like this, using a pointer instead of an iterator

```
XXXX* i = graph->adjLists[src];
while (i != NULL)
{
    if (!visited[i->vertex])
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    i = i->next;
```

From the code you've posted I cannot say what `XXXX` should be, but hopefully you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Close, but no, it is not correct. It would need to look more like this:

```c
node *current = graph->adjLists[src]; // start at the head of the list
while (current != NULL)
{
    if (!visited[current->vertex])
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    current = current->next;
}
```

Obviously, replacing `node` with whatever the real type of your list nodes is.